# Как сравнить примерную похожесть русских текстов используя обработку естественного языка?

Tags: java, python, машинное-обучение, nlp

Как сравнить примерную (частичную) похожесть двух русских текстов, учитывая синонимы и разные формы выражения текстов?
Какие еще есть варианты кроме NLP?
Например, выражение "Метод equals определяет отношение эквивалентности объектов" и "equals определяет равенство между объектами" можно считать как одно и то же.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ну, чтобы заматчить "отношение эквивалентности" и "равенство" нужно будет использовать Word2Vec, причём на словесных 1-2-граммах и обучить его на соответствующем корпусе, в котором эти выражения встречаются. (Ну, или взять готовую модель обученную). В остальном можно попробовать нормализацию и TF-IDF.

Comment: А "Закрой замок на замок, чтобы замок не замок" можно считать эквивалентом "Укрепленное строение требуется  надежно закрывать специально предназначенным для этого приспособлением, чтобы оно не отсырело"?

Comment: А "Закрой замок на замок, чтобы замок не замок" можно считать эквивалентом "Укрепленное строение требуется надежно закрывать специально предназначенным для этого приспособлением, чтобы оно не отсырело" - таких сложных выражений точно не будет.